# TypeScript decorator instead of extends

Tags: typescript, types, decorator, typescript-typings, deno

I Have an class Names **BaseController** and another called **MainController**(I'm **not** using any framework, my runtime is *deno* latest version)
I want MainController to extends BaseController without using 'extends' keywords
(using a decorator)

I tried this decorator but got unkown type error

`deno 1.34.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) v8 11.5.150.2 typescript 5.0.4`
(I'm on deno  linux x86)

```
function Controller() {
    return function (targetClass: any) {
        return class extends BaseController {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                // super(name);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example.